# How to get wlan tranmission statistics?

Tags: transmission

How to get the actual number of transmission by the hardware of wlan0?

When a device communicates with other over wireless network, the actual data transfer and the actual wireless transmission on the hardware are different. How to get the statistics of hardware transmissions?

Answer (score 0):

Run `ifconfig` in your terminal.

The numbers `RX bytes` and `TX bytes` should tell you the number or received and transmitted bytes respectively.